# Java: detect language RTL in a Spring web application without using AWT component?

Tags: java, web, internationalization

I am doing a Spring web application.

I have access to the locale and I need to whether it is RTL (right-to-left).

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192382/is-there-any-way-to-detect-an-rtl-language-in-java), it appears that it can solve my problem. However, the solution there:

```
ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(new Locale(System.getProperty("user.language"))).isLeftToRight();
```

uses Java AWT's component (ComponentOrientation).

I am wondering whether I can get RTL info about a locale without using AWT components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the locale's `.getLanguage()` is one of the right-to-left languages (Hebrew, Arabic, etc). This is actually how the function is implemented in AWT.

```
public static ComponentOrientation getOrientation(Locale locale) 
{
        // A more flexible implementation would consult a ResourceBundle
        // to find the appropriate orientation.  Until pluggable locales
        // are introduced however, the flexiblity isn't really needed.
        // So we choose efficiency instead.
        String lang = locale.getLanguage();
        if( "iw".equals(lang) || "ar".equals(lang)
            || "fa".equals(lang) || "ur".equals(lang) )
        {
            return RIGHT_TO_LEFT;
        } else {
            return LEFT_TO_RIGHT;
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for digging into AWT's source code for see how it is done. Smart thinking!

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes: Hebrew is now `he` rather than `iw`, but see caveat and additional languages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20821395