# Converting from windows-1256 to UTF-8 causes punctuation issue

Tags: java, character-encoding, right-to-left, google-cast, bidi

I have an Arabic subtitle I've trying to convert from SRT to VTT. The subtitles seems to be using windows-1256 according to the character encoding detector on ICU (Java). The final VTT file is on UTF-8.

The subtitle converts fine and it all looks right except for the punctuation moves from the left side to the right side. I am using this subtitle on the Chromecast so at first I thought it was an issue with the Chromecast but even gedit on Linux has the issue. However LibreOffice does not have the issue. Nor does the console output on IntelliJ.

I wrote a simple piece of code to recreate the issue without actually converting from SRT to VTT, just by converting from windows-1256 to UTF-8.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("arabic sub.srt"), "windows-1256")
);
String line = null;
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("bad punctuation.srt"), "UTF-8")
);
while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
    System.out.println(line);
    writer.write(line);
    writer.write("\r\n");
}
writer.close();
reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("bad punctuation.srt"), "UTF-8")
);
line = null;

while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Here is the output from the IntelliJ console:

[image: Intellij Console]

As you can see the dot is on the left side which I guess is correct.

Here is what gedit shows:

[image: gEdit]

Most of the text is to the right which I guess is correct but the period is on the right, which I guess is wrong.

Here is LibreOffice:

[image]

Which is mostly correct, the punctuation is to the left, however the text is also on the left and I guess it should be on the right.

This is the subtitle I'm testing https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/5168225/game-of-thrones-fire-and-blood-ar

I also tried a different SRT that was originally encoded as UTF-8 and that one worked fine without issues. So my guess is that the conversion from windows-1256 is the issue.

So what is the issue with the way I'm re-encoding the file?

Thanks.

Edit: Forgot a chromecast picture.

[image]

As you can see the punctuation is on the wrong side.

EDIT: I just noticed that Linux `chardet` says it is `MacCyrillic` not `windows-1256`. But the Java ICU library says `windows-1256`. Anyways, if I use `MacCyrillic` then the punctuation looks fine on gEdit but the text itself doesn't look right, like it is now using garbage characters.

Comment: I don't know much about displaying right-to-left text, but it's not unlikely that two tools have the same bug when it comes to complicated stuff like mixing scripts with different directionality (I assume the period displayed on the wrong end is the same that is used in English). I suggest you add the `right-to-left` and/or `bidi` tags to attract more experts in that domain.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Concerning your last edit: Windows-1256 and MacCyrillic are both 8-bit encodings, which means it's really hard to automatically guess the right encoding (because there are few patterns in the byte sequences). I'm pretty sure MacCyrillic is wrong though, since you already know the text is Arabic, and the Arabic language is typically not written with the Cyrillic script.

Comment: That would explain why the text looks like garbage then. I just noticed that if I open the original srt on gedit using `windows-1256` then the punctuation is on the right side as well. I'm wondering if the original file was just badly created.

Comment: Please add appropriate parts of all `.srt` files **and _console output_** as **_text_** instead of screenshots to ensemble a [mcve]  fully.

Comment: Isn't the encoding going to be lost when I paste it here? that's why I went through the trouble of making screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the original subtitles file, I can tell for sure that it is **badly formatted**. The full-stops seem to appear before the text even when it is displayed with a left-to-right character set. I believe the correct character set is windows-1256 though.

The only way this would display correctly is if the punctuation at the beginning of the line is displayed LTR while the rest of the line is displayed RTL. You could try to force this by adding a UTF-8 left-to-right mark right after the punctuation.

If you prefer to fix the original file instead, you would need to move any punctuation from the beginning of the line to the end. The brackets at the beginning of the line would also need to be reversed.

Comment: This sounds like the best explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the encoding has nothing to do with text orientation (LTR vs. RTL) I think you should leverage the UTF-8 marks specifically created for this purpose.

- left-to-right mark: ‎ or ‎ (U+200E)
- right-to-left mark: ‏ or ‏ (U+200F)

In a nutshell: the text file does not have the information of the text orientation, it's just a text file.

Cf. https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H34.html

Comment: I don't read that language but according to the user the issue is the punctuation not the whole text. This is exactly what he said: "Yes the text reads normally. Its just the last punctuation in the row that gets dragged the opposite side."

Comment: Yes, that's because the characters are in the correct order on the lines. My hunch is that the punctuation (in this case the full stop which is on the wrong side) is in one or more tools "corrected" based on LTR/RTL. In this case the UTF-mark **may** solve the problem.

Comment: Interesting, but how would I know when I need to do that to files I'm converting and when I don't have to do it? Thanks.

Comment: That depends on the language itself. See this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4192464/5471574